# Wordpress JSON API

Tags: php, json, wordpress, api

Hey guys i have been so far in luck with the JSON API i love it but i encouter this little problem with it comes to making multiple query in the same custom function.

```
            global $json_api;
            $result = array();

            $category = $json_api->introspector->get_categories();

            foreach($category as $value){

                    if($value->id !== 1 && $value->id !== 69 && $value->id !== 68 && $value->id !== 66){

                            $search_args = array(
                                    'cat' => $value->id,
                                    'order' => 'DESC',
                                    'post_status' => 'publish'
                            );

                            $search_limits = array(
                                    10 => array(
                                            'limit' => 4
                                    ),
                                    5 => array(
                                            'limit' => 2
                                    ),
                                    3 => array(
                                            'limit' => 3
                                    )
                            );

                            $json_api->query->count = ($search_limits[$value->id]['limit'] === null ? 1 : $search_limits[$v$
                            $result['posts'][$value->id] = $json_api->introspector->get_posts($search_args,true);
                    }
            }  

            return $result;
```

i hardcoded some of the values just to make it more straight foward, the issue is that when i make one query i get value ID lets say [10330][10218][10202] according to the category im looking for. Then i make this same query but with another category ID. But same result happens. So i was wondering is due to some sort of caching in the API if so can i turn it off for this query ?

Thanks in advance :D

Comment: Please let us see the query

Comment: The query is done through the API
                             $result['posts'][$value->id] = $json_api->introspector->get_posts($search_args,true);

Comment: The thing is that maybe 'get_posts' is the one with the problem. Your code seems fine so it might be the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well what do you expect the issue is that i was not reseting my queries apparently.

```
wp_reset_query();
```

did the trick.